# Why $\langle 2\rangle =\{0,2,4,6\}\neq\mathbb Z_8$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a little trouble in understanding why $\langle 2\rangle =\{0,2,4,6\}\neq\mathbb Z_8$?

Why is $2$ not a generator of $\mathbb Z_8$?

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_8$ has $8$ elements. Your question shows that $1$ isn't in the additive subgroup generated by $2$.

Comment: It generates the unique maximal ideal of $\mathbf Z/8\mathbf Z$.

Comment: You have answered it in your question.  $1,3,5,7\notin <2>$.

Comment: 1,3,5,7 is not generated by 2.

Comment: Note that $\langle 2\rangle$ is ambiguous without context. Is it a group or a ring, say?

Comment: @Shaun Well, it happens not to be ambiguous in a quotient of $\mathbb Z$, but yes, in principle the poster should be alert to this issue and to, say, tag the question appropriately with [group-theory] or [ring-theory]! It wouldn't do any good to get complacent in a nice ring like this and run afoul of the distinction later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take modulo $8$ operation then $\langle 2\rangle=\{2\cdot n:n\in \mathbb Z\}=\{2, 4, 6, 0\}$ i.e. we get only *four* values cyclically. But  $\mathbb Z_8$ has $4$ more elements $1,3,5,7$ which are not generated by $2$

Comment: Now, I ran some calculation, only 1,3,5,7 mod 8 can generate all 8 elements, therefore, only 1,3,5,7 are generators of $Z_8$, right?

Comment: yes! this is right.

Comment: This solution *doesn't imply* that all of $1,3,5,7$ generates $\mathbb Z_8$. It just eliminates $2$ from the list of generators of $\mathbb Z_8$.However by calculating order of elements or by calculating explicitly the subgroups $\langle 1\rangle ,\langle 2\rangle,\langle 3\rangle ,\langle 4\rangle,\langle 5\rangle ,\langle 6 \rangle,\langle 7\rangle ,\langle 0\rangle$ it can be shown that all of $1, 3, 5, 7$ generates $\mathbb Z_8$

Answer (score 2):

The ideal $\langle 2 \rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is by definition the set
$$\{2a \mid a \in \mathbb{Z}_8\}.$$
As such, it only contains $0,2,4,6$, as you can directly see by doubling all eight elements of $\mathbb{Z}_8$.
As eight is still a rather small number, you can see this without any deeper inside. Of course, it might be nice to understand it better. In this case, you might think about why 
$$\langle k \rangle = \mathbb{Z}_n$$
holds if and only if $gcd(k,n) = 1$.

Comment: Why $Z_8=\{1,3,5,7\}$? I understand $Z_8$ means integers of modulo 8, so 2 should be qualified? I have some missing information that blinds me from seeing what this means, please give me some hint.

Comment: No, your set $\mathbb{Z}_8$ will not work. You should  look up the definition you are working with and realize that $\mathbb{Z}_8$ is supposed to contain eight elements. As $\langle 2 \rangle$ only contains four, these two can then of course not be equal...

Answer (score 1):

Because $1\notin \langle 2\rangle$.